# NoMethodError (undefined method `encode' for JsonWebToken:Module)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jwt

I am facing a problem with JWT gem file after I upgrade my rails version from 4.2 to 5.0.

Can anybody please help me.

I am using Rails - 5.0.7.2
Ruby - 2.5.3
JwT - 2.2.1

```
require 'jwt'

payload = { data: 'test' }

token = JWT.encode payload, nil, 'none'

Traceback (most recent call last):
8: from bin/rails:11:in <main>' 7: from bin/rails:11:in require'
6: from /home/sahu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in <top (required)>' 5: from /home/sahu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in run_command!'
4: from /home/sahu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in console' 3: from /home/sahu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/console_helper.rb:9:in start'
2: from /home/sahu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/railties-5.0.7.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:65:in start' 1: from (irb):3 NoMethodError (undefined method encode' for JsonWebToken:Module)
```

I tried by downgrade the Jwt gem version but still facing same issue.

and also getting warnings like below -

```
/home/sahu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/json_web_token-0.3.5/lib/json_web_token.rb:36: warning: already initialized constant JWT
/home/sahu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/jwt-2.2.1/lib/jwt/base64.rb:5: warning: previous definition of JWT was here
```

Comment: Is that all code you have? I run this on my environment and works fine. So please give more code/context.

Comment: Do you have the same versions which I have? like rails, ruby, and JwT

Comment: yes, that why I ask you about more details

Comment: Thanks for the response. 
I am using  - Rails - 5.0.7.2
                   - Ruby - 2.5.3
                   - JwT - 2.2.1
as I mentioned the above and what are the more details you need?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the problem.
Before upgrading my rails version I have **JWT** Gem and After I Upgrade my rails version. I added a new gem **intuit-oauth**. This gem has a dependency on json_web_token gem. So after I installed **intuit-oauth** gem, It automatically installed **json_web_token** gem. Due to this gem, the **JWT** object was changed. like when I click on access **JWT** in the console. It returns as **JsonWebToken** object. Maybe this gem overrides **JWT** gem. So for a temporary solution, I removed **intuit-oauth** gem. and it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: You can place intuit-oauth gem before JWT gem. will give you the solution.